# Create spreadsheet with many columns w/python

Tags: python, architecture

I'm trying to parse data into a spreadsheet to create a report to distribute some data to our organization. I'm still pretty new to python and coding, but what I'm doing seems wrong. A co-worker mentioned I should create some objects and use the objects in a dictionary to output to a csv. My current code is somewhat like this.

```
#Create obj
obj(hostname, description, ..., status)

#Create csv
with open(<filepath>, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    #create the headers
    fieldnames = ['field1', 'field2', ..., 'field15']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for (id,obj) in dict.items():
        item = {'field1': obj.hostname, 'field2': obj.description, ..., 'field15':obj.status}
        #Add to the csv
        writer.writerow(item)
```

My co-worker mentioned instead of creating an object and declaring all attributes in that area that I may want to create methods(?) to grab the data allowing it to be more mutable. Kind of like this.

```
#Create obj
class obj:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hosts = set([])

    def addHost(self, hostname):
        self.hosts.add(hostname)

    def removeHost(self, hostname):
        self.hosts.remove(hostname)

    def setDescription(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.description
```

With the large amount of attributes for each object this has become quite a long list under the class declaration. This is what makes me wonder if it's the wrong way to do the process. I've no training and I can't find anything on the web beyond creating a spreadsheet with 3 or less rows. I've based my code on those examples, but it just seems clunky and fragile.

Answer (score -1):

I would say this follows what your co-worker suggests. This may be tedious, though it is why we separate the code for large classes into their own file. Or files of like classes.

You would be able to access the classes in another file if you have your main and the class in the same directory.

Let your code be your `main.py`, and have the class definition as `ObjClass.py` or similar. Then at just add an import to the top of your `main.py` file that you will be running.

```
from ObjClass import obj
...
#Create obj
obj = obj(hostname, description, ..., status)
```

You can get rid of the set methods by changing the `__init__` of your object to:

```
class obj:

    def __init__(self, description=None, ...=None, status=None):
        self.hosts = set([])
        self.description = description
        self. ... = ...
        self.status = status
```

This will allow you to define the arguments at initiation if you have them then change them later with:

```
obj.description = description
```

rather than

```
obj.setDescription(description)
```

Comment: Is it better to do what I currently have with the attributes declared in the initialization of the object or to initialize the object and then add the attributes later in the program? I was creating a separate file to import with the objects and methods and my plan was to create a blank object and add the data as I parsed through the data instead of adding all attributes in the initialization.

Comment: I would declare the objects themselves then add attributes later. This way if you don't have all of the attributes at initiation you will have no problem. If you have the attributes already stored at initiation of the object then maybe set them as optional parameters, giving you the ability to directly assign them as well!